# Изменение цвета в input .val jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня имеется текстовое поле ( input ), где вводится текст с тегами к примеру - &1Мой&eНикНейм

Тэг &1 означает, что весь текст после &1 нужно изменить на синий, а тег &e означает, что нужно изменить весь текст на желтый. При этом это все происходит в 1-ом input .

Я не могу понять как правильно их проверять ( по каждому символу отдельно мб), в общем мой код:

```
<div class="namecolorchange">
<center>
    <p style="color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Change name color</p>
    <input type="text" style="margin-bottom: 3px;" class="nameinput" name="nameinput">
    <span name="namedemo"></span>
    <input name="namebutton" type="submit" class="namebutton" value="">
</center>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "input[name='nameinput']" ).keyup(function() {
            var value = $( this ).val();
            $( "span[name='namedemo']" ).text( value );
            })
            .keyup();
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: опишите более подробно: цвет должен отображаться в самом input, или это лишь для определения цвета к отдельным словам?

Answer (score 2):

В самом `input` цвет менять не дано, да и не нужно это.
Можно так как-то:

```js
$(function(){
  $('input.namebutton[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
    var val = $('#myInputNick').val(), tmp;
    tmp = val.split('&1').map(function(e, i){
      return e.length > 0 && i > 0 ? '<span class="blue">' + e + '</span>' : e;
    });
    tmp = tmp.join('').split('&e').map(function(e, i){
      return e.length > 0 && i > 0 ? '<span class="yellow">' + e + '</span>' : e;
    });
    $('#view span').html(tmp.join(''));
    $('#view').css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
  });
});

// Тэг &1 означает, что весь текст после &1 нужно изменить на синий, а тег &e означает, что нужно изменить весь текст на желтый.
```

```css
#view{
  display: none;
}
.blue{
  color: blue;
}
.yellow{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="namecolorchange">
  <center>
    <p style="color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Change name color</p>
    <input type="text" style="margin-bottom: 3px;" id="myInputNick" class="nameinput" name="nameinput" value="&1Мой&eНикНейм" />
    <span name="namedemo"></span>
    <input name="namebutton" type="submit" class="namebutton" value="Change!">
    <div id='view'>
      <h4>View:</h4>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй для поиска использовать **indexOf**. В дальнейшем в зависимости от возвращаемого результата,формировать условие на изменение цвета